# iOS swift Apple reports my app crashes during TestFlight Review

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uiimage, testflight

Second time in a row got a reject on a TestFlight review from Apple. This time got crash logs from them, and apparently it appears that my app is crashing on async image download and caching (used in UITableView). Reviewed the code few times, but still have no clue what's wrong, the app working without crashes on devices and simulators, with and without the internet connection. Please take a look with a crashing line highlighted:

```
var imgCache = [String: UIImage]()

func downloadAndCacheImg(url: String?, completion: ((UIImage)->())?) {
    if url == nil { return }
    if let img = imgCache[url!] {
        completion?(img)
        return
    }
    if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: formatFileNameForCachedImg(url!)) {
        self.imgCache[url!] = img
        completion?(img)
        return
    }
    if let nsurl = NSURL(string: url!) {
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: nsurl), queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.imgCache[url!] = img    <<<<< CRASH HERE
                data.writeToFile(self.formatFileNameForCachedImg(url!), atomically: true)
                completion?(img)
            }
        })
    }
}

func formatFileNameForCachedImg(url: String) -> String {
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let dirName = dir[0] as! String
    var fname = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil)
    let out = String(format: "%@/%@", dirName, fname)
    return out
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the image? Have you tried a complete reset to simulator or the device to see if you can then produce the issue on a device that has never had your app on it?  I had similar issue and that is what I had to do to find the real cause of the issue.

Comment: Provide the full and symbolicated crash report.

Comment: Sorry, full report doesn't fit in comment, the interesting part is: `Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   navTo                          0x00000001000dd1a8 navTo.SharedAux.(downloadAndCacheImg (navTo.SharedAux) -> (Swift.String?, completion : (ObjectiveC.UIImage) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (SharedAux.swift:32)
1   navTo                          0x00000001000dc798 partial apply forwarder for navTo.SharedAux.(downloadAndCacheImg (navTo.SharedAux) -> (Swift.String?, completion : (ObjectiveC.UIImage) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (SharedAux.swift:0)`

Comment: FIXED here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241631/apple-claims-the-app-crashes-on-startup-during-review-cant-even-closely-reprod